# Unable to install pandas on pypy3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pypy

I use a Windows machine with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS). In my linux subsystem I integrated anaconda and created a pypy3.6 environment. I installed some packages without problems such as networkx and numpy but I can't integrate pandas. I know that pandas could be slower, I can't do without it for this project.

I used `pypy -mpip install pandas`

This is the error that is produced:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/pypy/bin/pypy /home/kuba/anaconda3/envs/pypy/site-packages/pip install 
--ignore-installed 
--no-user 
--prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-p5ojfkij/overlay 
--no-warn-script-location 
--no-binary :none: 
--only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple 
-- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 
'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' 
and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' 
and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' 
and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' 
and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' 
and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' 
and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; 
python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"''
```

I am a newbie in pypy, but it seems to be related to numpy.

```py
Python 3.6.9 (?, Oct 06 2020, 12:49:32)
[PyPy 7.3.2 with GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import numpy
>>>> numpy.__version__
'1.19.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find you have a better experience via [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-03-10-pypy/#how-to-use-pypy) since they pre-build the binary packages for you. Otherwise you will have to rebuild much of the scientific python stack.